# Python urllib post with different content type than urlencoded

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

It is my understanding that, I need to use url encoded content for posting with urllib. Is it possible to use application/json content type when posting with urllib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with urllib, as you'd need to set the `Content-type` header, and urllib does not provide a way to do so. You can do it however with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (but also not with `urlopen()` wich is more meant to "open files with a url" rather than submitting data):

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/', data="abc", headers={'Content-type': 'text/plain'})
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Personally, I prefer [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) (3d party) as a http client library.

Comment: Should also be mentioned that `data` must be a string instead of a dictionary

Comment: Can we have an update to this now that Python3 exists and `urllib2` has become `urllib`?